# How to get information about product in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, customer, quote

I want to get information about product in cart such as `customer_firstname`, `customer_email`.

I use this code:

```
$carts = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach( $carts->getAllVisibleItems() as $cart){
    var_dump($cart->getProduct()->getCustomerFirstname());
}
```

Its returns null although when I print `$cart` it returns data.

Comment: I don't think the customerFirstname is attached to the product, only to the cart. What exactly is var_dump($cart) printing?

Comment: You want to get the customers firstname for a product? Or just in general the customer?

Comment: My answer hasn't helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you cannot get the first name of a customer while in the cart unless that customer is registered and logged in.

which in that case you can do:

```
// Check if any customer is logged in or not
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    // Load the customer's data
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer->getFirstname(); // First Name
    $customer->getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
echo $quote->getData('customer_email');
echo $quote->getData('customer_firstname');
```

Tested in the cart template:

[image: test]

Using this solution you can get next customer data:

- 'customer_id'
- 'customer_tax_class_id'
- 'customer_group_id'
- 'customer_email'
- 'customer_prefix'
- 'customer_firstname'
- 'customer_middlename'
- 'customer_lastname'
- 'customer_suffix'
- 'customer_dob'
- 'customer_note'
- 'customer_note_notify'
- 'customer_is_guest'

Additional customer data can be received from the billing or shipping addresses:

```
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
```

#### Update:

First mistake in the code - when you call `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')` magento creates the new empty object of the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` class. Because of that you can not get data from it.

Second mistake - using of the `$cart->getProduct()->getCustomerFirstname()`. The quote item and the product from the quote item does not have information about the customer. This information is stored in the quote and quote addresses.